# Twitter timeline widget responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter

i have a Twitter Widget but im asking myself if its already responsive or do you need to make it responsive? Cause i didn't find something on google for it.

Do you guys know that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd give it a try.

You could also have a look at the following [page](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines). 
"A Twitter collection may be rendered in either a list or a responsive grid template." - Yes, it **can** be responive.